# Parse dictionary with Tuple as key

Tags: python, tuples

My dictionary with tuple as a key is as follows:

Key represents the x and y coordinates. (x, y)

```
D1 = {(10,12): 23, (8,14): 45, (12, 9): 29}
D2 = {(2, 8) : 67, (12, 10): 23, (14, 8): 56}
```

Now, from the above Dictionary, I would like to perform the following

1. Sort dictionary D1 based on Keys
2. Sort dictionary D2 based on Keys
3. Simply, print the keys and values in D1
4. Simply, print the keys and values in D2
5. Then do the following:

(pseudocode)

```
total = 0
For each key (x, y) in D1,  
   if D2.has_key((y, x)):
      total = total + D1[(x, y)] * D2[(y, x)]
   Print total
```

Comment: What have you tried? How didn't it work? We can't help if you don't tell us what your problem was - all you have done is list what you would like to do.

Comment: A dictionary can't be sorted. You can sort it into a list, though. Also, by which criteria do you want to sort the keys?

Comment: I have tried for key1, val1 in D1:    print key1, val1
It displays 8 14
12 9
10 12

Comment: start from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/python-dictionary-sort-by-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- (1/2) To sort a dict you have to use `collections.OrderedDict` (because normal dicts aren't sorted)
  Code:

  ```
  from collections import OrderedDict
  D1 = {(10,12): 23, (8,14): 45, (12, 9): 29}
  D1_sorted = OrderedDict(sorted(D1.items()))
  ```
- (3/4) Code: `print(D1)`
- (5) convert your code to python

  ```
  total = 0
  for x, y in D1.keys():
      try:
          total = total + D1[(x, y)] * D2[(y, x)]
      except KeyError:
          pass
  print total
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after (for your pseudo-code):

```
D1 = {(10,12): 23, (8,14): 45, (12, 9): 29}
D2 = {(2, 8) : 67, (12, 10): 23, (14, 8): 56}

total = sum(D1[k] * D2.get(k[::-1], 0) for k in D1.iterkeys())
# 3049
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> D1 = {(10,12): 23, (8,14): 45, (12, 9): 29}
>>> D2 = {(2, 8) : 67, (12, 10): 23, (14, 8): 56}
>>> D1 = OrderedDict(sorted(D1.items()))
>>> D2 = OrderedDict(sorted(D2.items()))
>>> print D1
OrderedDict([((8, 14), 45), ((10, 12), 23), ((12, 9), 29)])
>>> print D2
OrderedDict([((2, 8), 67), ((12, 10), 23), ((14, 8), 56)])
>>> sum(D1[(x, y)] * D2.get((y, x), 0) for x, y in D1)
3049
```